# How to prove an inequality through induction

Tags: real-analysis, formal-proofs

I am taking real analysis this semester and am confused on how to prove this inequality. It is

$\sqrt{2k+1} - 1 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}} \leq \sqrt{2k-1} $

I was thinking about trying to break the inequalities apart, and do two at at time in succession, proving the RHS and middle inequality. However, I'm not sure its even possible to prove through induction that an equation holds an inequality with a sum. So I am not sure how to approach this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

Comment: @WIll Jagy and I would be able to then prove it through induction?

Comment: no need. The fact above is by a simple diagram comparing sum with integral. You do need to fiddle a bit, the left hand integral comes straight, the right hand comes from $1 + \sum_2^k $

Comment: @WillJagy Well thank you for the  comment on that, thats very interesting and I'll keep note of that. The only issue is this questions asks to prove the inequality through induction, and I'm just not sure how thats possible.

Comment: he does the pictures  at https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/IntegralTest.aspx  in one of them the sum is bigger

Comment: Yes, induction should also work. You need to figure out the proper way  each of the left, middle, right, change when increasing $k$  to $k+1$  If that is not obvious, write it down in full for, say, $k=3,$  then for $k=4,$  the appropriate differences give all three terms

Answer (score 1):

@WillJagy's comment gives a nice way to do it, but since you seem to require induction, let's have it. I'll prove the right hand side inequality and leave the left hand side to do, it should be just as straightforward.

- $k=1$ : $ 1 \leq 1$ so the base case is satisfied.
- Assume that $ 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}}\leq \sqrt{2k-1}$ holds for some $k>1$. Now using this we get  \begin{align*}  1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}\leq \sqrt{2k-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}\end{align*}

We need to prove that $\sqrt{2k-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}\leq \sqrt{2k+1}$, a quick calculation shows this is true for $k\geq \frac{1}{2}$ so true for any positive integer, and we're done.

Comment: Thank you much!